# Imagemagick осветлить изображение

Tags: imagemagick, ubuntu

Как осветлить изображение в imagemagick, т.е. есть картинка .jpg формата, на белом фоне черным нарисована фигура или узор, нужно изменить цвет фигуры на серый.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-gamma число
или -contrast и +contrast
можно из черного сделать серым -colorspace GRAY